# How to predefine a Volley.newRequestQueue type and late init in onCreate function in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-volley

New to kotlin.

Short story: Seems `Volley.newRequestQueue()` returned a `A started RequestQueue instance`. But when I `var queue: Volley.RequestQueue`, it shows error `Unresolved reference: RequestQueue`.

Long story:
I made a simple single page app, as newRequestQueue shouldn't be inited multi times, I have to set an internal var first, then init it in `onCreate`, but it doesn't work?

```
class FullscreenActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var queue: Volley.RequestQueue

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    }

    fun a() {
        /** some codes to create the JsonObjectRequest first **/
        val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(....)

        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
    }

    fun b() {
        /** some codes to create the JsonObjectRequest first **/
        val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(....)

        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
    }
}
```

How can I reuse `Volley.RequestQueue` if I init it in `onCreate`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just initialize `queue` directly?

```
class FullscreenActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    fun a() {
        /** some codes to create the JsonObjectRequest first **/
        val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(....)

        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
    }
```

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple#simple

Another option is the singleton solution:
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue#singleton